# Postgres Pg_Dump failed due to non english character on database name

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I have created a postgres data base by giving non ascii name example: "Química"

When I tried to take back up of the same database using following command I am getting the exception

> pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "Química" failed: FATAL:  database "Química" does not exist.

Command used:

```
--host 127.0.0.1 --port 7555 --username postgres --format=d --verbose   --jobs=10 --compress 9 --file "C:\Delete\Archive" --dbname "Química" --schema "Archive_TVT"
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the output of the psql command `\l` ([edit] your question do not post additional information in comments)

Comment: To answer the question, we would need the output of the following commands: `psql -Atq -c "SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datname LIKE 'Qu%'" | od -t x1` and `echo Química | od -t x1`.

Comment: This didnt worked, we created database in UTF8 Encoding using nonAsccii characters, its easily reproducible.